# Set NGSelect component (third party) value programatically

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I am using NGSelect component for dropdown purpose https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select.

```
<ng-select
           class="custom"
           [items]="items"
           bindLabel="Name"
           bindValue="Id"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedId">
</ng-select>
```

Items can be any object with `Id` and `Name` in it. It can be

```
 [
        { Id: '1', Name: 'Vilnius' },
        { Id: '2', Name: 'Kaunas' },
        { Id: '3', Name: 'Pavilnys' }
    ];

OR
     [
            { Id: '1', Name: 'US' , States:10},
            { Id: '2', Name: 'Japan', States:23},
            { Id: '3', Name: 'Australia', States:67}
        ];

OR any object with Id and Name in it
```

My question is how do I set the value in this dropdown component programmatically. For e.g. I want to set `Australia` on `ngOnInit`, how to do it?

Code below does not work

```
TS File:

selectedId!: string;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedId = "3";
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't this `selectedId = "3";` give an error? should be `this.selectedId = "3";` Anyway is your `items` array initialized correctly?

Comment: @MaksatRahmanov, tx for pointing. corrected the question. array Items is correctly initialized in my case.

Comment: checkout  this example https://9gwqz.csb.app/

Comment: @MoufeedJuboqji, i can see it working in your example. Strangely not working on my code base.

Comment: compare the code  in app module and component